# App Crashing Trying to Add to SQLite Database in Fragment

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm trying to add a database into my application so that the information a user enters is stored into it.  Currently, I have the user entering a player's first name and last name, and my app works perfectly.  Then I try to add the first and last name into the database and everything crashes when I click the "Add Player" button to submit the player.

The commented out line in the "addPlayer" method of this fragment seems to be the culprit.  When I un-comment it, the app crashes; when it's commented, things seem to work fine:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;



/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class AddPlayerFragment extends Fragment {
    TextView addFirstName, addLastName;
    Button doneButton, nextButton;

    String playerNames = "";

    PlayersDatabaseHelper db = new PlayersDatabaseHelper(getActivity());

    public AddPlayerFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
         final View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_player, container, false);


         //Define buttons on the view.
         doneButton = view.findViewById(R.id.doneAddingPlayers);
         nextButton = view.findViewById(R.id.addPlayer);

         //Get player names.
         if(getArguments() != null){
             playerNames = getArguments().getString("playersSoFar");
         }

         /*
         Set onClickListener method for "Add Another" button.
         Call addPlayer method to get user-entered player name, add name to players array list.
         Re-open this view to enter another player.
         */
         nextButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 String newPlayerName = addPlayer(view);
                 if(newPlayerName != "") {
                     if (playerNames != null) {
                         playerNames = playerNames + ", " + newPlayerName;
                     } else {
                         playerNames = newPlayerName;
                     }

                     Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), AddPlayerActivity.class);
                     intent.putExtra("playersSoFar", playerNames);
                     startActivity(intent);
                 }
             }
         });

         //Set onClick Listener method for "Done" button.  Opens grid for new game with player names.
        doneButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String newPlayerName = addPlayer(view);
                playerNames = playerNames + "," + newPlayerName;

                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ScoringGridActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("players", playerNames);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

         return view;

    }

    public String addPlayer(View view) {
        String playerFirstName, playerLastName, playerName;

        addFirstName = view.findViewById(R.id.newUserFirstName);
        addLastName = view.findViewById(R.id.newUserLastName);

        playerFirstName = addFirstName.getText().toString();
        playerLastName = addLastName.getText().toString();
        playerName = playerFirstName + " " + playerLastName;


        if(playerFirstName.isEmpty()) {
            //Toast letting user know first name is required.
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.required_name_toast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return "";
        }

        else{
            //db.addPlayer(new PlayerInfo(playerFirstName, playerLastName));
        }

        return playerName;
    }



}
```

Here's the code for my SQLiteDBHelper class:

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import com.schrumpfk.candlepinscorecard.PlayerInfo;

class PlayersDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DB_NAME = "player information";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

    PlayersDatabaseHelper (Context context){
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE PLAYER_INFO ("
                + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + "FIRST_NAME TEXT, "
                + "LAST_NAME TEXT) ;");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PLAYER_INFO");
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS PLAYER_INFO ("
                + "FIRST_NAME TEXT, "
                + "LAST_NAME TEXT) ;");
        this.onCreate(db);

    }

    public void addPlayer(PlayerInfo playerInfo){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("FIRST_NAME", playerInfo.getFirstName());
        contentValues.put("LAST_NAME", playerInfo.getLastName());

        db.insert("PLAYER_INFO", null, contentValues);
        db.close();
    }
}
```

Logs from crash:

```
06-11 17:28:06.621 2636-2676/com.schrumpfk.candlepinscorecard D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa1bec5c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa1be9730)
06-11 17:28:06.800 2636-2676/com.schrumpfk.candlepinscorecard D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa1bec5c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa1be9730)
06-11 17:28:06.911 2636-2676/com.schrumpfk.candlepinscorecard D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa1bec5c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa1be9730)
06-11 17:28:06.928 2636-2676/com.schrumpfk.candlepinscorecard D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa1bec5c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa1be9730)
06-11 17:28:06.963 2636-2676/com.schrumpfk.candlepinscorecard D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa1bec5c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa1be9730)
06-11 17:28:06.968 2636-2676/com.schrumpfk.candlepinscorecard D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x946ab000 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x9452ca50
06-11 17:28:07.350 2636-2676/com.schrumpfk.candlepinscorecard D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa1bec5c0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xa1be9730)
06-11 17:28:08.662 2636-2640/com.schrumpfk.candlepinscorecard I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=18KB, data=26KB
    After code cache collection, code=16KB, data=26KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
06-11 17:28:09.035 2636-2636/com.schrumpfk.candlepinscorecard W/IInputConnectionWrapper: finishComposingText on inactive InputConnection
06-11 17:28:09.414 2636-2640/com.schrumpfk.candlepinscorecard I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=56KB, data=56KB
    After code cache collection, code=56KB, data=56KB
    Increasing code cache capacity to 256KB
06-11 17:28:11.612 2636-2636/com.schrumpfk.candlepinscorecard D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM


    --------- beginning of crash
06-11 17:28:11.613 2636-2636/com.schrumpfk.candlepinscorecard E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.schrumpfk.candlepinscorecard, PID: 2636
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase android.content.Context.openOrCreateDatabase(java.lang.String, int, android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase$CursorFactory, android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler)' on a null object reference
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:223)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getReadableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:187)
        at com.schrumpfk.candlepinscorecard.PlayersDatabaseHelper.addPlayer(PlayersDatabaseHelper.java:38)
        at com.schrumpfk.candlepinscorecard.AddPlayerFragment.addPlayer(AddPlayerFragment.java:110)
        at com.schrumpfk.candlepinscorecard.AddPlayerFragment$1.onClick(AddPlayerFragment.java:60)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Comment: Can you attach your Logs output on the crash? That would be the best place to start as it will give a lot of contextual information about what's happening.

Comment: Sure, good idea.  I'm adding them to the bottom of my original post.

Comment: I posted below, but the issue is `getActivity()` is likely null when you initialize `db` in your fragment.

Comment: PlayersDatabaseHelper db = new PlayersDatabaseHelper(getActivity()); this line is an issue... move db = new PlayersDatabaseHelper(getActivity()); inside onCreateView and i hope it will work....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no guarantee that `getActivity()` in a `Fragment` will not be null when you initialize the `Fragment`. If you have things that you need when the `Fragment` is beginning but require a non-null `Context` you should listen for `onActivityCreated()` (see [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle))), or `onAttach()` (see [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onAttach(android.content.Context))) as this lets you know the `Fragment` is now associated with an `Activity` or `Context`.

Comment: Thanks, adding onAttach() fixed the crash.

Answer (score 0):

The context passed to the `PlayersDatabaseHelper` is null when you create the instance. That's because you're using `getActivity` inside the fragment at a time when you don't have an activity attached yet.

If you look at the lifecycle diagram for a fragment [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRxIQ.png) you can see that the activity is attached later on and not when the fragment is created.

I'd suggest moving the creation of `PlayerDatabaseHelper` to `onAttach`.

Comment: Thanks, adding onAttach() and moving PlayerDatabaseHelper there fixed the crash.